# How can I grant root through ADB root?

Tags: adb, root-access, lineageos

I'm using LineageOS. I can run `adb root` and then ADB shell, and I have root access to the device. I'm trying to use [Neo Backup](https://github.com/NeoApplications/neo-backup) which requires root.

Is there a method, with root ADB access, to grant root access to the Neo Backup application?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to grant certain apps root permission through ADB?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/225313/44325)

Comment: is your device rooted?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to grant an app root access without GUI interaction?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/216499/how-to-grant-an-app-root-access-without-gui-interaction)